# Thymeleaf: Conditional th:value

Tags: thymeleaf

**Problem:**
`${map}` can be `null`.

```
<input type="text" th:value="${map.name}" />
```

**What I need:**
If `name` is not `null` then `th:value=name` otherwise `th:value=""`

```
 <input type="text" th:value="${map.name != null ? map.name : ''}" />
```

But my above code is not valid

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
<input th:value="${map !=null}? ${map.name} : ''" />
```

**Or Better (with Elvis Operator):**

```
<input type="text" th:value="${map?.name}"
```